# Run command prompt commands in c#

Tags: c#, ip-address, nslookup

Is there any way to run command prompt commands from within a C# application? I need the name of a computer but the only way I can access it is by typing in to the cmd prompt.

**nslookup *myIPAdress***

Like if my ip was 134.123.12.12 I would type;

**nslookup 134.123.12.12**

And the value it returns after **Name:** is what I am after. How would I get this in a c# console application?

I've already tried using

```
string name1 = Environment.MachineName;
Console.WriteLine(name1);
string name2 = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
Console.WriteLine(name2);
string name3 = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").HostName;
Console.WriteLine(name3);
string name4 =DNSLookup("134.123.12.12");
string name5 = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(134.123.12.12).HostName;
Console.WriteLine(name5);
```

But none of these produce the correct name, they just give me the server/host name of the computer. Any ideas?

Comment: regarding `run command prompt commands from within a C# application` google turned up a lot of help

Comment: That value should be what you get by doing `GetHostEntry` with the IP instead of 'localhost' (like you did with `name3` above)

Comment: @Joe GetHostEtry returns the host name, which isn't the name I'm looking for.

Comment: That's what `nslookup` does.  Can you post the specific output you're seeing and expect?  That's what `Name:` is supposed to be.

Comment: If you want to execute a dos command use something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: I downvoted because the title does not match the problem and it shows not enough research.

Comment: When I run nslookup with my ip it will give me                       Server: *server name*                                             Address *other IP address*                                                 BUT below that it will then give me                                    Name:*given computer name - what I'm after*                                    Address *My IP address*  Since I can't what I need through direct coding I was hoping to just run a cmd prompt command in my console application to get the name.

Comment: You should be able to get what you want through direct coding.  nslookup should give you the host name from DNS (that's what `nslookup` does).  You aren't explaining what you expect to see instead.

Comment: I figured it out after for anyone else who was wondering. I used this code



**string strCmdText;**

**strCmdText = "/k nslookup 134.123.12.12";**

**System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe", strCmdText);**



Before I was putting /c infront of my nslookup to close the window after. /k launches it correctly though. Thanks for your suggestions though!

Answer (score 1):

I got some code that might work for you.

Here it will give you your internet name:

```
string name = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("192.168.1.254").HostName;
Console.WriteLine(name);
Console.ReadLine();
```

And here is will give you your IP address:

```
System.Net.IPHostEntry host;
string localIP = "?";
host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());
foreach (System.Net.IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
{
    if (ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    {
        localIP = ip.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(localIP);
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
return;
```

This might not be the best way to do it but it works!

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

This will execute whatever command you put after /C.

```
 string CmndTxt;
 CmndTxt = "/C your command;
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", CmndTxt);
```

For example:

```
 string Cmndtxt;
 CmndTxt = "/C ping " + IPtextBox.Text;
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", CmndTxt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use:

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostByAddress("134.123.12.12").HostName
```

Comment: That will give you an error because you will at least need to add a: ";", Maybe even 2 parentheses.

Comment: That method has been marked as deprecated since at least .NET 3.5. It seems to work, but it tells you to use `GetHostEntry` instead.